# Displaying Recent Forum Topics last_author avatar

Tags: ee2, forum

On our home page we have a list of the latest forum entries - see http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/forum/recent_forum_topics.html. The only thing that is missing is the last_author avatar.

So far I've been trying to get around it with using the last_author ID and replace the image. Example: `<img src="/images/avatars/uploads/avatar_{exp:low_replace find="site_url/SITE_INDEX/" replace=""}{last_author_profile_path}{/exp:low_replace}.jpg">` , but if course I get in to trouble if the member have something else then .jpg image.

Have anyone found a solution and will I have to do a hack to the module?

Thanks!
John

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should develop a small plugin which would take {last_author_profile_path} as parameter. In the plugin code, fetch the last segment of last_author_profile_path and search it within the directory with PHP functions like `strstr` or `preg_match` and output the full name of avatar image (with image extension).

It would work for you.